# Is my RNN being trained only on 1 or 2 samples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have created an LSTM-RNN of 7 cells. It reduces the loss but accuracy remains zero. I have been unable to find out why until I saw the keras training console output. Below is a sample from the latest training run.

```
Epoch 500/500
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 0.1505 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Does 2/2 mean that training is happening only on two samples? I have 7168 datapoints and my batch size is explicitly stated as 7168 then why does it happen? Below is my code

```py
import pandas
import scipy.io as loader
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy
import time
import math
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

additional_metrics = ['accuracy']

loss_function = BinaryCrossentropy()

number_of_epochs = 500
optimizer = SGD()
validation_split = 0.20
verbosity_mode = 1
mini = 0
maxi  = 0
mean = 0
"""

"""
def myfunc(arg):
    global mini, maxi, mean
    return (arg - mean) / (maxi - mini)

# k = 0
cgm = numpy.load('cgm_train_new.npy')
labels = numpy.load('labels_train_new.npy')
labs = list()
cgm_flat = cgm.flatten()
mini = min(cgm_flat)
maxi = max(cgm_flat)
mean = sum(cgm_flat) / len(cgm_flat)
cgm = numpy.apply_along_axis(myfunc, 0, cgm)

for each in labels:
    # suma = suma + sum(each)
    if each[-1] == 1: labs.append(.99)
    else: labs.append(.01)

RNNmodel = Sequential()

RNNmodel.add(LSTM(7, activation='tanh'))
RNNmodel.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
RNNmodel.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_function, metrics=additional_metrics)
cgm_rs = numpy.reshape(cgm, [len(cgm), 7, 1])
ans = numpy.reshape(labs, [len(labs), 1, 1])

history = RNNmodel.fit(
    cgm_rs,
    ans,
    batch_size=7168,
    epochs=number_of_epochs)#,
    # verbose=verbosity_mode)#,
                  #  validation_split=validation_split)



tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    RNNmodel,
    to_file="RNNmodel.png")
answers = RNNmodel.predict(cgm_rs)
# for each in answers:
    # print(each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have understood my error. No need for any answers. Thank you.